# Weird behavior of conditional operator?

Tags: c#, .net

```
string sortedcolumn =
( dataGridView1.SortedColumn != null
? dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name
: "username"
);
```

In above statment when `dataGridView1.SortedColumn==null` I get exception of `dataGridView1.SortedColumn` is null instead of getting value as `"username"` to `sortedcolumn` var.

Any idea?

Comment: Which eception do you get? On which words of code? Does it happen also when you change it to regular if..else statements?

Comment: Are you sure that you get the NullReferenceException on SortedColumn rather than on dataGridView1?

Comment: This is not the null coalescing operator, it is the tertiary condition express.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes:

- `dataGridView1` is a field or variable containing the value null.
- `dataGridView1` is a property getter that returns null.
- `SortedColumn` is a weird property getter that returns something non-null the first time but null afterwards. (Very unlikely because then merely looking at it in the debugger would change the result.)
- `dataGridView1`, `SortedColumn`, or `Name` is a property getter that throws the exception you are seeing.
- `dataGridView1.SortedColumn` is of a type that overloads `operator!=`, which throws the exception you are seeing.
- `dataGridView1.SortedColumn.Name` is of a type that implements `implicit operator string`, which throws the exception you are seeing.